# How do I remove the blank space on the left in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I had WebStorm 18.1.1 installed previously and just upgraded to WebStorm 18.1.2. The editor now has a blank space on the left.

[image: 1]

Its width is fixed whether the sidebar is open or not. It can't be resized.

[image: 2]

If I click on the area, I can mark the line.

[image: 3]

If I enable split editor by moving a tab to the right, it disappears.

[image: 4]

But if I switch back to single tab per window, the blank space comes back. Is this a WebStorm feature that aligns the contents of the window in the center or a bug in the new version? How do I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a Distraction Free mode enabled. In this mode the editor content is centred. You can exit it in the menu View - Exit Distraction Free Mode.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot.